# Managing Terraform multiple environments with Git

Tags: git, terraform

I've researched and watched a few videos about the best way to manage multiple environments but I am still confused about how to manage it in a better way.

Let's say I have a single repository with the following structure:

```
main.tf
variables.tf
backend.tf
dev/
   variables.tfvar
   backend.dev.hcl
prod/
   variables.tfvar
   backend.production.hcl
```

Then, in my repository I have two branches (dev and main).
Does it make sense to have production variable values committed to my dev branch? What's the best way following any best practices to handle this scenario?

My last question, once there is any change committed to the dev branch, what is the best way to merge the changes to prod branch without missing any dev/prod terraform configuration?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you look into Terraform workspaces? Can't say it's 100% suitable for your case not knowing what kind of development is happening. But I think It's worth discovering :D

Comment: Thanks vidura. I have looked at Terraform workspaces but I feel like my doubts are more around how to push Terraform code from dev to Prod. For example, tfstate is stored in a bucket but if there is any changes into dev environment, it will update a tfstate file locally. Do I need to commit this file and then push to Prod branch too? That would mess up (overwrite) Prod tfstate file.

Comment: One fundamental Terraform principle is not to commit the state file to any version controlling systems. And also we should not modify the state file out of Terraform. So the idea of workspace is to maintain several state files for a single configuration. Here you may need to maintain 2 infrastructures for 2 environments but a single configuration.  In the configuration file, you can specify how resources should be created based on the active workspace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to this question typically depends on whether you are talking about multiple deployment stages for the Terraform configuration *itself*, or multiple deployment stages for whatever applications/services you'll be running on the Terraform-managed infrastructure.

One way to think about this distinction is to think about what you'll be using the multiple stages to achieve. If your goal is to have somewhere to try running `terraform apply` before you do it in production then you're talking about multiple deployment stages of the Terraform configuration. If your goal is to create a long-lived staging environment for you to deploy your application/service into then typically the staging environment is also "production" from the perspective of your deployment pipeline, and so should typically be treated as such.

---

To test your Terraform configurations prior to applying them to "real infrastructure", you can use [Terraform CLI workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/workspaces.html) to create temporary additional states associated with your configuration, so you can try applying changes without affecting the main infrastructure represented in the "default" workspace:

- `terraform workspace new temp-test` to create a temporary workspace.
- Use your version control system to select whichever commit was most recently applied in the `default` workspace. This will typically be on the main branch of your version control repository, although depending on how you use VCS you might need to select an earlier commit to exclude any changes that haven't been applied to the real system yet.
- `terraform apply` to create equivalent infrastructure to the default workspace to be the basis for your test.
- Use your version control system to switch back to the configuration you're intending to test. This will typically be a feature branch in your repository, possibly attached to a pull request. In a real version of this workflow, it might be helpful to name your temporary workspace after your branch name so your colleagues can easily see which branches and workspaces go together.
- `terraform apply` again to plan and apply the changes represented by the new configuration.
- If the apply succeeded, inspect the infrastructure it created to make sure it's functioning in the way you intended.
- When you're done:

  - `terraform destroy` to destroy the `temp-test` infrastructure
  - `terraform workspace select` to get back to the default workspace
  - `terraform workspace delete temp-test` to delete the temporary workspace

For this to work you'll need to be careful to avoid colliding with existing production objects in situations where a remote system requires unique names. For systems that have a sense of accounts with separate namespaces a common choice would be to use a different account and entirely separate credentials for the test, which then means you can use the remote system's access controls to avoid accidental disruption of the "real" infrastructure.

---

To create a long-lived staging or development environment for testing some higher-level component during its own deployment pipeline calls for a different strategy: in that case, the infrastructure supporting the staging environment is part of "production" as far as the application's deployment process is concerned, and so should typically be modeled as such.

To achieve that while ensuring that the two infrastructure stacks remain equivalent aside from intentional differences, factor your common infrastructure code out into one or more [modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/) and then call those modules once for the production infrastructure and again for each other environment's infrastructure.

Depending on the intended failure domains for your system you might choose to represent both the production and staging infrastructure together in a single configuration, containing two calls to the same module:

```
module "network-production" {
  source = "../modules/network"

  cidr_block = "10.1.0.0/16"
  # etc...
}

module "network-production" {
  source = "../modules/network"

  cidr_block = "10.2.0.0/16"
  # etc...
}
```

or, to ensure that they are both independently maintainable, you could write two separate configurations that both call into the same module and `terraform apply` them separately.

In both cases, the idea here is to represent the inevitable differences between your different environments using input variables to your common modules, but keep the declared resources the same in both cases, but to treat both of them as "production infrastructure" from the application pipeline's perspective by keeping them both in a namespace named `default`, either in one configuration or across multiple, and by using the same main branch in your version control to represent the "latest versions" of both of them at once.

If you want to test changes to your configurations that together represent all of the environments your application's pipeline rely on, you can combine these two approaches by creating a temporary workspace representing either your entire stack or one particular environment and applying configuration from a branch into that stack before you merge it to the main branch and apply it to the default workspace.

---

This answer is an elaboration of the guidance in the Terraform documentation [When to use Multiple Workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/workspaces.html#when-to-use-multiple-workspaces).

Ultimately though, this is a situation where you have a few different options with different tradeoffs and I'd encourage you to review this advice and the other related context in the documentation and decide for yourself which of the advice best matches your needs. Terraform is a general tool intended for solving a variety of different problems, and ultimately only you can map your specific set of requirements onto Terraform's features.

Comment: Hi Martin, I really appreciate your detailed answer. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!